# Merge two php functions in a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, scripting, merge, calendar

I'm using a Calendar plugin and there's one thing I would like to change

There's a php function that adds the event name:

include/Calendar/Calendar.class.php

```
$tab .= '<div class="namevent"> '.$event['event'].'</div>';
```

Output: **My event name**

I would like to add a TIME in the event title, after looking for a while I found the time functions in

public/events.php

```
if(!empty($custom['stime'][0]))
                            echo '<br /><strong>'.$home[16].':</strong> '.$custom['stime'][0].' ';

if(!empty($custom['etime'][0]))
                            echo '<strong>'.$home[17].'</strong> '.$custom['etime'][0];
```

Output: **10:00 to 11:00** (supposing your event time are these)

So then I tried this:

```
$tab .= '<div class="namevent"> '.$custom['stime'][0].' - '.$custom['etime'][0].' '.$event['event'].'</div>';
```

Expeting the output to be: **10:00 - 11:00 My event name**

But it didn't work;

What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please add the name of the Wordpress plugin..

Comment: I'm sorry: 3C-Events : Wordpress All-in-One Event Calendar (I think Gaaks has this plugin)

http://codecanyon.net/item/3cevents-wordpress-allinone-event-calendar/2382407

Comment: That's CodeCanyon, if you bought the item, you can directly ask to the author.. I don't think lots of people can help you here, we don't have the API without buying the item.. You can ask at the [author support forum](http://freelanceonweb.com/forum/index.php).

Comment: ah... Am I in the right way at least? ._.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `$custom['stime'][0]` and `$custom['etime'][0]` exist, with a `var_dump()` or `print_r()` on each.
Add the following code just before your line which causes the error :

```
var_dump($custom['stime']);  // Be sure the var is not undefined and [0] exists
var_dump($custom['etime']);
```

Comment: Please delete your pastie.org paste, the author would not be happy.. Btw, you can see in your image that you have only `NULL` values, so `$custom['stime']` and `$custom['etime']` are null. That's your problem. Try a `var_dump($custom);` too.

Comment: right, deleted the comment. var_dup($custom); still causes NULL :/

Comment: Yep, so you have to read the doc and use a variable which exists.. If I'm right, change `$custom` to `$event`.